# Determining a direction/projection/heading for an object in 3D space after it has been rotated

Tags: kinematics, coordinate-systems, rotational-kinematics, simulations

I hope this is a good place to find an answer. Regardless, Worldbuilding looks like a great forum to follow.

I'm not a math wiz and I've tried to tackle this problem many times over the past decade or so.

I have a 3D space world, and I'm in a little space ship. I travel from point to point based on map waypoints. My game interface would allow me to rotate my (stationary for this example) ship in a gimbal fashion. What do i need to do to capture my new heading and project a new point to move to if I just rotated my ship and decide to travel forward? It would also be nice to capture something relative between the two rotations. There will be no real time movement in this example, although I understand lerp is a method to interpolate if I decided to up the complexity.

I've been through https://gamemath.com/ several times over the years, but what I think I am missing is a way to visualize or visually plot what's going on and see that the math functions work as intended, along with a way to practice.

Is Euler my solution, or matrices or quaternions best for my application? Like I mentioned, math has never been a strong point and I will never truly understand these concepts, so my best bet is to get help picking the best method and then implement it the best I can.

I've worked on this for long periods of time over the years, then end up dropping it as I cannot come up with a solution. The last time I tried I had dropped the entire project idea once and for all as it became hopeless to me to ever solve this step. Though even now a couple of years later, it still pulls at me and I cannot shake the desire to build my thing.

Comment: I'm feel this is not a World Building problem, but a Game Design problem. That is - you aren't looking for a solution on how ships *within* your world navigate, you are looking for the best way for the player *outside of the world* to plot a course.

Unless I've misunderstood the question.

Comment: First person or third?

Comment: First Person perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are familiar with the general concept of roration: there are three axes about which your ship can rotate, specifically the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes (where the $x$-axis is forward/backward, the $y$-axis is left/right, and the $z$-axis is up/down). Rotation about the $x$-axis is called "roll", rotation about the $y$-axis is called "pitch", and rotation about the $z$-axis is called "yaw".

Consider the velocity vector that your ship has, $v$. The vector will actually have three components: $$v=\begin{pmatrix}v_x\\v_y\\v_z\end{pmatrix},$$ one corresponding to each axis.

This vector can easily be rotated! Well, easily by a computer's standards. The best method is **matrix multiplication**, which uses a matrix to rotate the vector about the origin. You can also consider a rotation to be a vector:

$$a=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\\\gamma\end{pmatrix}.$$

Here, $a_x$ represents the rotation about the $x$-axis and so on. Using these two vectors, you can compute the rotated vector by multiplying the vector $v$ by the **rotation matrix**. I recommend the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) on the topic for more information about how specifically to implement the matrix. If you can implement 3D matrix multiplication in your game, you can do rotation too.

Comment: Thank you @controlgroup. The formulas in the wiki beyond my comprehension unfortunately. I do understand the basic concept of what you posted. I wish there was a prebuilt simulation that I could somehow practice the matrix multiplication and receive some sort of visual feedback.

Comment: I do as well; I struggled to understand 3D rotations desperately for a while. Don’t worry, there are built-in libraries like NumPy for Python as well as others for other languages that can do matrix multiplication and vector rotation automatically.